# How to lock only cell content in Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, locking, apache-poi, cell

I am working on exporting some data to Excel using Java POI library. Some of the cells in this data have to be read-only. I make it by:

```
CellStyle lockedCell = workbook.createCellStyle();
lockedCell.setLocked(true);
cell.setCellStyle(lockedCell);
```

and after it:

```
workbook.getSheetAt(workbook.getActiveSheetIndex()).protectSheet("");
```

It works quite well, but there is one problem - I cannot modify the width of columns containing locked cells.

Is it possible to lock only the content of the cells, so that I could modify columns width?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that it is possible to only allow user-width-modifications on locked cells.

What you can do instead is, after populating the data, call `autoSizeColumn(colNumber);` on the sheet for each column populated.

```
int colMaxLength = workbook.getActiveSheetIndex().getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
HSSFSheet activeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(workbook.getActiveSheetIndex());
for(int i = 0 ; i < colMaxLength ; i++){
   activeSheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
}
```